# Change background color of a cell when next value is different from the preceding one

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've been around for years on Stack but this is my first time posting. I'm working on a website (php + mysql) and the following problem is driving me absolutely nuts.

I have a table with 2 columns: Size and Amount. The table is generated by a basic php script simply outputting values stored in the database as rows in the table. Super basic, no fancy stuff there:

```
SELECT Size, Amount FROM database WHERE product = 'product123' ORDER BY Size ASC
```

The php echo outputs an html table displaying Size and the corresponding available packs (Amount).

```
Echo '<td>'.$record['size'].'</td><td>'.$record['amount'].'</td>'
```

Some Sizes are available in different Amounts, so therefore a particular Size can appear multiple times. Example:

```
Size | Amount
1    | 10
1    | 50
2    | 10
2+   | 10
3    | 40
3+   | 25
3+   | 40
4+   | 25
```

**What I'm looking to achieve is that rows containing the same Size have the same background color.** So it should alternate, grouped by Size, and this is irregular unfortunately. Example:

```
Size | Amount
1    | 10     < yellow
1    | 50     < yellow
2    | 10     < transparent
2+   | 10     < yellow
3    | 40     < transparent
3+   | 25     < yellow
3+   | 40     < yellow
4+   | 25     < transparent
```

So if the next Size is different from the preceding one, the row background color should change. This way a single Size is alternately highlighted as a group. Note that Size 2 and 2+ (same for 3 and 3+) are considered to be different sizes, hence the background color should change.

I can't figure out how to achieve this with php. The difficulty is that I can't use an evaluation based on odd/even since there sometimes is a "+" involved, making not all Sizes numeric values. *Changing the naming scheme to get rid of that "+" is not an option unfortunately.*

I was thinking of somehow having php check, while generating the table row by row, if the next outputted Size is identical to the preceding one. If yes: no change in bg-color. If no: change bg-color. However I can't figure out what the best way is to code something like this. Any pointers in the right direction are much appreciated.

Comment: so size is a varchar ? what drives what the actual color is ?

Comment: You can pretty much do what you said which is if they are sorted by size, you just check if previous is the same as current, then if so, same color. If not, then new color. You can can also sort your returned results in groups based on size as the `key` using a loop,  then loop one more time through those groups., perhaps imploding to save on more loops.

Comment: Yes, it's a varchar. I forgot to mention that. The actual color is only driven by a change in Size. So when the next Size is different from the preceding one in the table a row color change should happen.

Comment: i can do it only in mysql if you want, otherwise use the php solutions below

Comment: I'm not sure yet what the best route is. How would you achieve this using only mqsql?

Comment: You can not really achieve this layout only using mysql. Sorting, sure, but the layout with alternating colors, I don't think that is possible.

Comment: it is possible @Rasclatt

Comment: @Drew I thought the OP was referring to the whole process, you can not render a `<table>` layout to the page, using only mysql. A stored procedure for the query is a good idea, props for that!

Comment: @Drew unless you can...I have never heard of (or have seen) such a thing, but I guess it could exist...I don't know everything, that's fore sure! I am also not proficient in mysql so a stored procedure wouldn't have even crossed my mind.

Comment: i'm just talking about the alternating part @Rasclatt. Even if I could render chunks of html out (and I can), I would never show it. The backlash would be horrific

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much after you answered, but it's definitely a good angle. I will have to learn more about mysql, I don't really use it to that level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
// your data
$records[] = array('size' => "1");
$records[] = array('size' => "1");
$records[] = array('size' => "2");
$records[] = array('size' => "2+");
$records[] = array('size' => "3");
$records[] = array('size' => "3+");
$records[] = array('size' => "3+");
$records[] = array('size' => "4");

$lastSize = $records[0]['size'];
$color = "yellow";

foreach ($records as $record) {
    if ($lastSize != $record['size']) {
        $lastSize = $record['size'];
        if ($color == "yellow") $color = "transparent";
        else $color = "yellow";
    }
    $lastSize == $record['size'];
    echo $record['size'].' - '.$color.'<br>';
}

// OUTPUT:
// 1 - yellow
// 1 - yellow
// 2 - transparent
// 2+ - yellow
// 3 - transparent
// 3+ - yellow
// 3+ - yellow
// 4 - transparent
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we'll start at the end. You probably want to put your color on the `<tr>`. The cleanest way to do it would be using css classes.

```
if ($newSize) {
    echo '<tr class="tranparentRow">';
} else {
    echo '<tr class="yellowRow">';
}
```

We'll figure out how to get the right value into `$newSize` in a moment. Next, we need the css for classes above, so make sure this is in your styles somewhere:

```
.transparentRow {
    background-color: transparent;
}
.yellowRow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Ok, lets rip the `+` off the size:

```
$plainSize = trim($record['size'], '+')
```

Ok, we use that for comparison, using an ever changing `$oldSize` valiable. Here is a full, functional, block:

```
$oldSize = 0;
foreach($whatever as $record) {
    $plainSize = trim($record['size'], '+')
    if ($plainSize == $oldSize) {
        $newSize = false;
    } else {
        $newSize = true;
    }
    $oldSize = $plainSize;

    if ($newSize) {
        echo '<tr class="tranparentRow">';
    } else {
        echo '<tr class="yellowRow">';
    }

    echo '<td>'.$record['size'].'</td><td>'.$record['amount'].'</td>';
    echo '</td>';
}
```

Some cleanup can lead to this:

```
$oldSize = 0;
foreach($whatever as $record) {
    $plainSize = trim($record['size'], '+')
    if ($plainSize == $oldSize) {
        echo '<tr class="tranparentRow">';
    } else {
        echo '<tr class="yellowRow">';
    }
    $oldSize = $plainSize;

    echo '<td>'.$record['size'].'</td><td>'.$record['amount'].'</td>';
    echo '</td>';
}
```

I hope that helped not just with this problem, but with an example of how you can approach many other problems. Start at the end, work your way back.

Answer (score 0):

you can keep the current size on a variable and if it changes you can change the color.

```
    <html>
<head><title> Sample - Menukz </title></head>
<body>
<?php
    /* Sample data array with size and amount */
    $product['product123'] = array
                  (
                  array("size"=>"1", "amount"=>10),
                  array("size"=>"1", "amount"=>50),
                  array("size"=>"2", "amount"=>10),
                  array("size"=>"2+", "amount"=>10),
                  array("size"=>"3", "amount"=>40),
                  array("size"=>"3+", "amount"=>25),
                  array("size"=>"3+", "amount"=>40),
                  array("size"=>"4+", "amount"=>25)
                  );

    $pre_size=0;
    $pre_init=1;

    echo "<table>";

    foreach($product['product123'] as $row)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        /* Initialize */
        if(strcmp($pre_size, $row['size']) !== 0 && $pre_init ===1)
        {
            $pre_size = $row['size'];
            $pre_init = 0;
        }
        /* Change track */
        if (strcmp($pre_size, $row['size']) !== 0 && $pre_init ===0)
        {
            echo "<td>Changed ... </td><td>".  $row['size'] . "</td><td>" . $row['amount'] . "</td>"; 
            $pre_size = $row['size'];
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<td>Not Changed ... </td><td>".  $row['size'] . "</td><td>" . $row['amount'] . "</td>";           
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }   
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't get this one to work with the while loop used to fetch the records from the db. With every fetch of a record $record['size'] is always reset to the next value next in line to be pulled from the database. So $current_size and $record['size'] will always be identical. Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

As my comment suggested, use a double `foreach()` + `implode()` *(and yet another solution)*:

```
<?php
$array[]    =   array("size"=>1,"amount"=>50);
$array[]    =   array("size"=>2,"amount"=>10);
$array[]    =   array("size"=>"2+","amount"=>10);
$array[]    =   array("size"=>3,"amount"=>40);
$array[]    =   array("size"=>"3+","amount"=>25);
$array[]    =   array("size"=>"3+","amount"=>40);
$array[]    =   array("size"=>"3+","amount"=>25);
$array[]    =   array("size"=>'4+',"amount"=>30);

// Sort by size
foreach($array as $row) {
        $new[$row['size']][]    =   $row['amount'];
    }
?>
    <table>
<?php
    $i = 0;
    // Loop through the sorted groups
    foreach($new as $size => $amts) {
        // Determine odd or even
        $color = ($i % 2 == 0)? "yellow":"transparent";
?>      <tr>
            <td class="<?php echo $color; ?>"><?php echo $size; ?></td>
            <td class="<?php echo $color; ?>"><?php echo implode("</td>".PHP_EOL."</tr>".PHP_EOL."<tr>".PHP_EOL.'<td class="'.$color.'">'.$size.'</td><td class="'.$color.'">',$amts); ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php       $i++;
        }
?>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using php sessions like this

```
  session_start();
    $_SESSION["pre_val"]='not set';
    $_SESSION["pre_class"]='transparent';

//in your loop for showing table
//your loop starts
  if($_SESSION["pre_val"]==$record['size']){
    $suitable_class=$_SESSION["pre_class"];
  }
  else{
       if($_SESSION["pre_class"]=='yellow'){$suitable_class='transparent';}
       else{$suitable_class='yellow';} 

   }
//setting current values to session
$_SESSION["pre_class"] = $suitable_class;
$_SESSION["pre_val"]   = $record['size'];

Echo '<tr class="$suitable_class"><td>'.$record['size'].'</td><td>'.$record['amount'].'</td></tr>';
//your loop ends
```

in your css

```
.yellow{background-color:yellow;}
.transparent{ background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);}
```

hope this solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Some for loop fun while printing out the table

```
$rows = array(
    array("size"=>"1" ,"amount"=>"10"),
    array("size"=>"1" ,"amount"=>"50"),
    array("size"=>"2" ,"amount"=>"10"),
    array("size"=>"2+","amount"=>"10"),
    array("size"=>"3" ,"amount"=>"40"),
    array("size"=>"3+","amount"=>"25"),
    array("size"=>"3+","amount"=>"40"),
    array("size"=>"4+","amount"=>"25")
);

echo "
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Size</th><th>Amount</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>";
$bgColors = ['transparent','yellow'];
$bgColor = 0;
echo "
        <tr>
            <td class='" . $bgColors[$bgColor] . "'>" . $rows[0]["size"] . "</td><td>" . $rows[0]["amount"] . "</td>
        </tr>";
for($i = 1, $max = count($rows), $lastSize = $rows[0]; $i < $max; $lastSize = $rows[$i], $i++) {
    if($rows[$i]["size"] !== $lastSize["size"])
        $bgColor = ($bgColor + 1) % 2;
    echo "
        <tr>
            <td style='background-color:" . $bgColors[$bgColor] . "'>" . $rows[$i]["size"] . "</td><td>" . $rows[$i]["amount"] . "</td>
        </tr>";
}
echo "
    </tbody>
</table>";
```

And an unasked for JS solution (assuming you've printed out the table as usual)

```
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('#sizeTable tbody td[name=size]');
var bgColors = ['transparent','yellow'];
var bgColor = 0;

for(var i = 1, lastSize = rows[0], max = rows.length; i < max; lastSize = rows[i],i++) {
    if(rows[i].innerHTML !== lastSize.innerHTML) {
        bgColor = (bgColor + 1) % 2;
    }
    rows[i].style['background-color'] = bgColors[bgColor];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using a nested repeat region.

First select your product by group `WHERE product = 'product123' GROUP BY size`

```
<?php
require ('conn.php');
try {
    $prod = 'product123';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sizes WHERE product=:prod GROUP BY size";
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindValue(':prod', $prod, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $totalRows = $query->rowCount();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('failed!');
}
?>
```

Then get all the products in each group ordered by amount inside a nested repeat region.

Each "grouped row" will alternate colors.

```
<table width="200" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td>Size</td>
    <td>Amount</td>
  </tr>
  <?php
  $i = 0;
  do {
    $i = $i + 1;
    if ($i % 2 == 0){
    echo '<tr bgcolor=#E4E4E4><td colspan="2">';
        } else {
    echo '<tr bgcolor=#EEEEEE><td colspan="2">';
    }
  try {
    $group = $row['size'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sizes WHERE size=:group ORDER BY amount ASC";
    $nested = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $nested->bindValue(':group', $group, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $nested->execute();
    $row_nested = $nested->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $totalRows_nested = $nested->rowCount();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('nested failed');
}
  echo '<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200">';
  do {
      echo '<tr><td width="100">'.$row_nested['size'].'</td><td width="100">'.$row_nested['amount'].'</td></tr>';
  } while ($row_nested = $nested->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
  echo '</table>';
  echo '</td></tr>';
  } while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
  ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the proposed solutions. Berriel's MCVE works like a charm! However Stack doesn't let me +1 the answer yet.

**I have one additional question:**
I also have a second table in which the output of the first column can be any article code consisting of 10 chars limited to [a-z][0-9]. Since there is no predefined scheme such as in the Size table, I can't hardcode/predict any output like in most of the proposed solutions. However I still want to color the rows it in the same way described in my opening post.

I am not familiar with Stored Procedures or PDO in mysql. Is there any way to work around arrays with predefined content and still achieve the color grouping of rows with the same article code?